# Field norm restricted to groups of units in local fields

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

> Let $K$ be a local field (i.e. a field on which there exists a discrete additive valuation $v$). Let $O_K$ be the elements $x$ in $K$ with $v(x)\ge 0$ and let $M_K$ denote the set of elements in $K$ with $v(x)>0$.
>   Let $U_K^{(s)}=1+M_K^s$ be the group of $s$-units in $O_K$, where $s\in \mathbb N$. Now
>   Let $K_n$ be an unramified extension of $K$ of degree $n$, which is Galois and cyclic, ie $Gal(K_n/K)\cong \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ and define the corresponding $O_{K_n}, M_{K_n}$ and $U^{(s)}_{K_n}$ in the same way (it is well known that $v$ extends uniquely to $K_n$). Show that the norm of an element in $U^{(s)}_{K_n}$ lies in $U^{(s)}_{K}$, namely $\text{Nm}_{K_n/K}(U^{(s)}_{K_n})\subset U^{(s)}_{K}$.

My only idea was to pick uniformizers $\pi_K$ and $\pi_{K_n}$ in $K$ and $K_n$ respectively. Let $x=1+\mu \pi_{K_n}^s$ from $U^{(s)}_{K_n}$, for $\mu \in O_{K_n}$ and let $\sigma$ be a generator of the Galois group.
Then $\text{Nm}(x)=(1+\mu \pi_{K_n}^s)(1+\sigma(\mu) \sigma(\pi_{K_n})^s)...(1+\sigma^{n-1}(\mu) \sigma^{n-1}(\pi_{K_n})^s)$.
Then I would use the fact that the extension is unramified, but as $s$ gets larger, the computations get messier and messier, which makes me think I am on a wrong track.

I was also curious whether this property holds even if the extension was not unramified, but say, still cyclic.

(I am using terminology of Neukirch's book from chapter 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Galois extension $L/K$ of local fields, the effect of the norm map $N=N_{L/K}$ on the filtration $U_L^n$ is completely known. The best reference , I think, is Serre's book "Local Fields", chap. 5 and 14.

Chap. 5 considers an extension $L/K$ of local fields with group $G$, such that the residual field extension is separable. The unramified case is easy: if $x=1+y$, with $y \in M_L^n$, one has $\sigma (x)=1+\sigma (y)$ for all $\sigma \in G$, and $\sigma (y)\in M_L^n$, so that the product of all the $1+\sigma (y)$ is congruent to $1+$ the sum of all the $ \sigma (y)$ modulo $M_L^{2n}$ ; if $L/K$ is unramified, $M_L^n \cap K = M_K^n$, and we are done.The general case is a combination of the non ramified and totally ramified cases. It remains to solve the latter case. For this, one introduces the so-called Hasse-Herbrand function $\psi (n)$ attached to the totally ramified extension $L/K$ in order to study the effect of the map $N_n : U_L^{\psi(n)}/U_L^{\psi(n)+1} \to U_L^n/U_L^{n+1}$ induced by the norm, and one shows that $ker N_n\cong G_ \psi (n)/G_ {\psi (n)+1}$, where $G_r$ denotes the $r$-th ramification subgroup in the lower numbering. If the residual field is perfect and $N_n$ is injective, it is also surjective. If the residual field is finite, one can derive an isomorphism $\delta_n: U_K^n/U_K^{n+1}N(U_L^{\psi (n)}) \cong G_ \psi (n)/G_ {\psi(n)+1}$ .

In chap. 15 , to go further, one supposes that the residual field of $K$ is finite and $G$ is abelian. The reciprocity isomorphism of local CFT induces an isomorphism $\omega_n : U_K^n/U_K^{n+1}N(U_L^{\psi (n)}) \cong G^n/G^{n+1}$ in the upper numbering. The Hasse-Arf theorem states that $G_ \psi (n)=G^n$, and one can show the following comparison result : $\omega_n (x) = \delta_n (x^{-1})$ for all $x \in U_K^n/U_K^{n+1}N(U_L^{\psi (n)})$ ./.